# std::exception while starting server (WinSock2)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winsock2

I am new to C++ and I am currently learning from a [tutorial](https://translate.google.de/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.c-worker.ch%2Ftuts%2Fwstut_op.php&edit-text=&act=url) how to use winsock(2).
However I run into a problem with my server. I have no idea how it happens.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <winsock.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

void cmdError(string e = ""){
    cout << "Error:\n" << e << endl;
    chrono::milliseconds t( 3000 );
    this_thread::sleep_for( t );
}

void startServer(int port){
    SOCKET acceptSocket;
    SOCKET connectedSocket;
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port=htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr=ADDR_ANY;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
    long rc;
    acceptSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(acceptSocket = INVALID_SOCKET){ throw new exception();}
    rc = ::bind(acceptSocket, (SOCKADDR*) &addr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
    if(rc == SOCKET_ERROR){ throw new exception();}
    rc = listen(acceptSocket, 10);
    if(rc == SOCKET_ERROR){ throw new exception();}
    connectedSocket = accept(acceptSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if(connectedSocket == INVALID_SOCKET){ throw new exception();}
}

void startClient(string ip, int port){
    long rc;
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(s == INVALID_SOCKET){ throw new exception();}

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip.c_str());
    rc = connect(s, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(SOCKADDR));

    if(s == SOCKET_ERROR){ throw new exception();}
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
    WSADATA wsa;
    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsa) != 0){
        cmdError();
        return 1;
    }
    string n;
    int port;
    cout << "Please specify the task of this thread. \nEnter 'server' or 'client'." << endl;
    getline(cin, n);
    system("cls");
    cout << "Please specify a port." << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.sync();
    cin >> port;
    system("cls");
    if(n.at(0) == 'c' || n.at(0) == 'C'){
        string ip;
        cout << "You started a client application." << endl;
        cout << "Enter the IP address of the server you want to connect to." << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.sync();
        getline(cin, ip);
        system("cls");
        cmdError();
        try{
            startClient(ip, port);
        }
        catch(exception e){
            cmdError();
            e.~exception();
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
    else if(n.at(0) == 's' || n.at(0) == 'S'){
        cout << "You started a server application" << endl;
        try {
            startServer(port);
        }
        catch(exception e){
            e.~exception();
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    cmdError();
    return 1;
}

void sendStr(string msg){
}
```

When I start my server through the application I get the following error popup in `void startServer(int port)`.

```
First-chance exception at 0x7667C42D in test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception:
std::exception at memory location 0x001EF5C8.

If there is a handler for this exception, the progrram may be safely continued.
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not catching what you're throwing. You're throwing an `exception *` and you're trying to catch an `exception`.

You should almost never throw a `new` exception, you should just throw an exception, you should then catch a const reference to said exception, so for example:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

int
x(int y)
{
    throw std::exception();
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    try {
        x(2);
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "Oops" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I used your code I get the program terminated due to an uncaught exception of type `std::exception *` (note that it's a pointer to `std::exception`, not a `std::exception`.

In addition, I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish with the `e.~exception();`. It has no place in that code. If you were trying to delete the exception that you had `new`d, then you should `delete` it. Explicit calls to destructors like this indicates that you're having difficulties understanding the object lifecycle; which is a fundamental part of the `C++` language.

> Charles Bailey's [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948316/throw-new-stdexception-vs-throw-stdexception) goes into some detail on the whys and whats of this also.

Comment: Upticked. And for the OP, note the *removal* of `e.~exception();`, which has no earthly business being there no matter what.

Comment: OK - I edited my code and changed what you suggested. I still get the same error though and as I said...I'm new to cpp so pls don't judge a student.

Comment: so you `throw exception();` and `catch (const exception &e)` and removed the `e.~exception();`? You're always going to fail your if conditions because you're using an assignment (single `=`) within the if, instead of the test `==`. So code like: `if (acceptSocket = INVALID_SOCKET)` won't test the value of acceptSocket, it will assign the value INVALID_SOCKET to it. If you ramp up compilation warnings to 4 - `/W4`, it would have said `assignment within conditional expression`.

Comment: Also, the `memset` is after assigning some values, which clears them - you need to `memset` first, then assign values to the struct. Finally, if you're going to throw an `exception`, throw one with a string value so you know **where** the exception comes from.

Comment: Thank you - that last thing did it