# Boost unit testing exception check failing strangely

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I'm basically lost on this one. I've looked at Boost doc plus searching on SO, but I don't seem to find a thing. Assuming a class modelling Fraction, I want to throw an exception when divider is to be set to 0.

```
void Fraction::setQ(int q) {
    if (q == 0){
        throw new std::logic_error("Divider must not be null");
    }else{
         q_ = q;
    }
}
```

And this code is tested with this block of code

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( NonZeroDivider ){
    BOOST_CHECK_THROW(
        f->setQ(0),
        std::logic_error
    );
}
```

But when boost should catch the exception, it doesn't and prints an error followed by a failure

```
unknown location(0): fatal error in "NonZeroDivider": unknown type
```

If you could help me on this one, I've tried BOOST_CHECK_EXCEPTION (with necessary editions) but no idea. Always the same behavior. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't throw an exception (`std::logic_error`), it throws a pointer to a dynamically allocated exception (`std::logic_error*`); see [throw new std::exception vs throw std::exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948316/throw-new-stdexception-vs-throw-stdexception).

The fix is to remove the `new` keyword:

```
throw new std::logic_error("Divider must not be null");
      ~~~~
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It worked. I'll read the thread you linked with attention :)