# Qt QException subclass thrown, but QUnhandledException caught

Tags: c++, qt, exception

I made a subclass of QException as follows:

```
#include <QtConcurrent>
#include <QException>

class ProcessingException : public QException
{
public:
    ProcessingException(QString const& message) :
        message(message)
    {}

    virtual ~ProcessingException()
    {

    }

    void raise() const { throw *this; }
    ProcessingException *clone() const { return new ProcessingException(*this); }

    QString getMessage() const
    {
        return message;
    }
private:
    QString message;
};
```

From a method that's run by QtConcurrent::run I throw an instance of this subclass with `throw new ProcessingException("test");`. Then if I understand the documentation properly, when I collect the future's result with `.waitForFinished()`, Qt should re-throw the QException subclass. However, using this approach I'm only able to catch a QUnhandledException:

```
try
{
    watcher->waitForFinished();
}
catch(const ProcessingException &e)
{
    qCritical() << "Caught:" << e.getMessage();
}
catch(const QUnhandledException &e)
{
    qCritical() << "Uncaught qexception!";
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are throwing a pointer but catching a reference....

Just use `throw ProcessingException("test");`. 
You can catch it by const reference and you don't have to clean up (call `delete`) after catching it.

Related: [throw new std::exception vs throw std::exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948316/throw-new-stdexception-vs-throw-stdexception)